# EF 4.1 - Problem accessing DB from same app on different machines

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I have deployed an application that uses EF to the same server as my DB. Obviously the first time I ran the app on the server the DB was created - no problems.

However, when I attempt to run the same application from my local machine using the same connection string / login details as the instance running on the server, I get this exception saying the model has changed, although it hasn't:

> The model backing the 'EkmDomainsDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database,
>   or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance.
>   For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will
>   automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it
>   with new data.

I assume this is something to do with the EdmMetadata table, but I am not sure exactly what. Can anyone shed any light on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existing databases do not generally need any database initializer so it can be turned off for your context type by calling:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDataContext>(null);
```

Comment: I am actually not calling SetInitializer at any point - are there defaults that are set up if you don't call the method passing null?

Comment: thanks this solved my problem, like I said what I was doing was not calling SetInitializer at all, which likely means a default initializer was set up

Comment: Entity framework actually calls drop create database if model changes by default unless the initializer is changed or removed